# Extract column name and specific value based on a condition

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose that I have the following data frame:

```
firstname <- c('Doug','Tom','Glenn','Billy','Angelo')
city <- c('Tulsa','Unknown','Miami','Houston','Unknown')
state <- c('OK','CA','FL','Unknown','Unknown')
job <- c('Unknown','Plumber','Professor','Unknown','Unknown')

list_test <- data.frame(firstname, city, state, job)
```

I want to extract the **firstname** and **column names** where one of the columns is Unknown. In other words, I want a table that looks like this:

```
  firstname  attribute
       Doug        job
        Tom       city
      Billy      state
      Billy        job
     Angelo       city
     Angelo      state
     Angelo        job
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
list_test%>%melt(id.var='firstname',variable.name='attribute')
          %>%filter(value=='Unknown')
          %>%select(-3)


firstname attribute
1       Tom      city
2    Angelo      city
3     Billy     state
4    Angelo     state
5      Doug       job
6     Billy       job
7    Angelo       job
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the names of the columns you want to process, building a data frame with all the first names that are missing that attribute. Then you can combine them all with `do.call` and `rbind`:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(tail(names(list_test), -1), function(x) {
  data.frame(firstname=list_test$firstname[list_test[,x] == "Unknown"], attribute=x)
}))
#   firstname attribute
# 1       Tom      city
# 2    Angelo      city
# 3     Billy     state
# 4    Angelo     state
# 5      Doug       job
# 6     Billy       job
# 7    Angelo       job
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution without loops; probably scales better for larger datasets.

```
library(reshape2)

#transform to long format
m_l <- melt(list_test,id = "firstname",factorsAsStrings=T)
#ignore warning; expected

#make selection
res <- m_l[m_l$value=="Unknown",-3]
#order (for completeness' sake)

> res[order(res$firstname),]
   firstname variable
5     Angelo     city
10    Angelo    state
15    Angelo      job
9      Billy    state
14     Billy      job
11      Doug      job
2        Tom     city
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple option using `tidyr`'s `gather` and base R `subset`

```
library(tidyr)
subset(gather(list_test, "firstname"), value == "Unknown")

#   firstname firstname.1   value
#2        Tom        city Unknown
#5     Angelo        city Unknown
#9      Billy       state Unknown
#10    Angelo       state Unknown
#11      Doug         job Unknown
#14     Billy         job Unknown
#15    Angelo         job Unknown
```

Comment: I like the response. I was preparing a "tidyr" and "dplyr" answer, but I saw so many different methods! :) "setDF" is from "data.table" right? I think "gather" has a problem (warnings) with strings as factors in this case.

Comment: Yes, they're definitely non important warnings as @liborm mentions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `tidyr` and `dplyr` solution. I find it way more elagant:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

list_test %>% 
  gather(field, value, -firstname) %>% 
  filter(value == "Unknown") %>% 
  select(-value) %>% 
  arrange(firstname)
```

Where the last two lines are rather cosmetic fixes. You can ignore the warning about dropping attributes. It's just telling you that it converted factor to character vector.

Comment: Looks I'm not the only one with Hadley's packages here, but at least it demonstrates the variety of ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` example:

```
library(data.table)
list_test <- data.table(firstname, city, state, job)
varlist <- names(list_test)[2:4]
do.call(rbind,sapply(varlist, function(x) list_test[get(x)=='Unknown',list(firstname,col = x)], simplify=FALSE))
```

It's a little messy - I'm hoping someone could suggest a better `data.table` approach.